# jQuery show requested tab on page load

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code for tabs on a site...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tab').click(function () {
        $('.tabs > li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $('div.tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active').removeClass('tab_contents_active');
        $(this.rel).addClass('tab_contents_active');
    });
});
```

Is there any way that I can load a specified tab from the url? For example: The default tab is "#tab1" but I want to load "#tab2" when a specified url is requested... basically I want "#tab1" to be default unless a URL like http://example.com/page.html#tab2 is requested...  is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your structure is like this for tabs (best I can guess):

```
 <li><a href="#tab2" rel="tab2" class="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
```

You can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.tab').click(function () {
        $('.tabs > li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        $('div.tab_contents_container > div.tab_contents_active').removeClass('tab_contents_active');
        $(this.rel).addClass('tab_contents_active');
    }).each(function() {
      if($(this).get(0).hash == location.hash) {
        $(this).click();
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass which tab you want in through the querystring, then use javascript to get that querystring variable and activate that particular tab.

Answer (score 0):

location.hash is a bit uncomfortable.

See [jquery.bbq plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

And just react on haschchange event, and trigger it instead of namually changing tabs.